# angular loader avoiding repetitive calls

Tags: angular, typescript

In my code below with the `this.button.nativeElement, 'click'` it triggers and show the loader and also calls the createUser method , now if there is error like 'First Name is required. or 'Last Name is required.' etc it should close the loader and return empty.

My issue is that showLoader is called multiple times or eveytime there is this.notificationService.showError , the code is called multiple times.

Is there a way to only call is once like if first name is empty then close loader , as you can see below the  this.closeLoader(); is called 7 times which for me is wrong. Any idea and help guys ? Thanks.

#code

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        tap(x => x),
        exhaustMap(ev => {
          this.showLoader();
          return this.createUser();
        })
      )
      .pipe(tap(x => x))
      .subscribe(this.handleResponse());
  }

  createUser(): Observable<any> {
    if(this.userStatus == 'USER_ON_NO_ACCOUNT') {
      if(!this.modelForm.get('firstName').value) {
        this.closeLoader();
        this.notificationService.showError('First Name is required.');
        return EMPTY;
      }
      if(!this.modelForm.get('lastName').value) {
        this.notificationService.showError('Last Name is required.');
        this.closeLoader();
        return EMPTY;
      }
      if(!this.modelForm.get('companyName').value) {
        this.notificationService.showError('Company Name is required.');
        this.closeLoader();
        return EMPTY;
      }
    }
    if(!this.modelForm.get('roleId').value) {
      this.closeLoader();
      this.notificationService.showError('Security Role is required.');
      return EMPTY;
    }
    if(this.modelForm.get('roleId').value && this.modelForm.get('roleId').value !== 7 && !this.modelForm.get('isSso').value) {
      this.closeLoader();
      this.notificationService.showError('SSO is required.');
      return EMPTY;
    }
    if(this.modelForm.get('roleId').value && this.modelForm.get('isSso').value && this.modelForm.get('isSso').value ==='Yes' && !this.modelForm.get('ssocredentials').value) {
      this.closeLoader();
      this.notificationService.showError('SSO Credential is required.');
      return EMPTY;
    }
    if(this.modelForm.get('isSso').value ==='No') {
      this.modelForm.get('ssocredentials').setValue(null);
    }
    return this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value).pipe(
        finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false ))
    );
  }

  handleResponse(): any {
    return {
      next: res => {
        this.closeLoader();
        this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
        this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
      },
      error: err => {
        this.closeLoader();
        this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isInProgress = false;
      },
      complete: () => this.isInProgress = false
    };
  }
  showLoader() {
    LOADER_DIALOG_CONFIG.data = { text: "Loading ..." };
    this.dialog.open(LoaderDialogComponent, LOADER_DIALOG_CONFIG);
  }
  closeLoader() {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
```

Comment: can't you show the loader (this.showLoader();) just before calling the create method in the accountService ?

Comment: yep agree, calling loader after validation is done is much more cleaner